# StateProvider Resolve not firing when minimized

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, minify, bundling-and-minification

Without minification, my code runs fine, but when it is minified, the load function is not called:

```
$stateProvider
    // logged-in pages ------------------------
    .state("app", {
        abstract: true,
        template: "<div ui-view></div>",
        resolve: {
            load: function (appStarter) {
                console.log("app.load");
                var appStarterPromise = appStarter.start();
                return appStarterPromise.then(function () {

                    $("body").removeClass("loading");
                });
            }
        }
    }).state("app.home", {
    //...
```

Any idea why this is not firing, or how to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    resolve: {
        load: ['appStarter', function (appStarter) {
            console.log("app.load");
            var appStarterPromise = appStarter.start();
            return appStarterPromise.then(function () {

                $("body").removeClass("loading");
            });
        }]
    }
```

This is how you inject dependencies, minification proof!

Comment: No problem @Sean, if you have issues regarding injection application wide, try this: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate This should help you out!

Comment: This is an approach you should use in your controllers, services etc too